# Let X and Y be independent random variables such that $E|X+Y|<\infty$. Is it true that $E|X|<\infty$? Give a proof or a counterexample.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X and Y be independent random variables such that $E|X+Y|<\infty$. Is it true that $E|X|<\infty$? Give a proof or a counterexample.

Thoughts: My intuition was to apply Fubini-Tonelli here since the expectations are integrals (sums). I think it's right but don't know where to start the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is pointing you in the right direction. Let $\mu_Y$ be the distribution of $Y$. Then 
$$
\infty>E|X+Y|=\int_{\Bbb R}E|X+y|\,\mu_Y(dy),
$$
which means that $E|X+y|<\infty$ for $\mu_Y$-a.e. $y\in\Bbb R$. You should be able to finish it from there.